# Cooperative groups in CUDA

Tags: cuda

since the CUDA 9 release apparently it is possible to group different threads and blocks into the same group so you can manage them together. That`s very useful for me because I need to launch a kernel with several blocks and wait until all of them are synchronized (cudaThreadSynchronize() is not worthy for me because after the threads are synchronized I have to continue working in my kernel).

What I have thought is to include these blocks of threads into the same group and wait until all of them are synchronized, as the examples of Nvdia main page suggest.

They do something like this:

```
__device__ int reduce_sum(thread_group g, int *temp, int val)
{
    int lane = g.thread_rank();

// Each iteration halves the number of active threads
// Each thread adds its partial sum[i] to sum[lane+i]
for (int i = g.size() / 2; i > 0; i /= 2)
{
    temp[lane] = val;
    g.sync(); // wait for all threads to store
    if(lane<i) val += temp[lane + i];
    g.sync(); // wait for all threads to load
}
```

My problem is how to group these blocks into the *g* group.
This is how I originally launched my kernel:

```
asap << <5, 1000 >> > (cuda_E2, cuda_A2, cuda_temp, Nb, *binM, Nspb);
```

Any time that I try to use *thread_group* the compiler says that it is undefied. I'm using the *cooperative_groups.h* header.

Does anyone know how to deal with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show the source code for _your_ function, rather than something you've pulled off Nvidia's website? It's likely you need to use `this_thread_block()` or `this_grid()` somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Quote from the [documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#ixzz4xkUNPdTX):

> Cooperative Groups requires CUDA 9.0 or later. To use Cooperative
>   Groups, include the header file:
>
> ```
> #include <cooperative_groups.h>
> ```
>
> and use the Cooperative Groups namespace:
>
> ```
> using namespace cooperative_groups;
> ```
>
> Then code containing any
>   intra-block Cooperative Groups functionality can be compiled in the
>   normal way using nvcc.

The namespace is what you are missing.

Comment: Hi and many thanks for your help. I'm new with the concept of namespace, I'm reading some stuff but I don't know how to apply it here, Could you help me?

Comment: there are cuda sample codes that demonstrate use of CG.  You might want to study one of them such as the reduction CG example. Also, for the cooperative grid sync that you want (any synchronization across blocks today can only be accomplished via cooperative grid) requires an alternate launch syntax..  You cannot use the `<<<...>>>` syntax.  This is covered in the relevant section in the programming guide and a fully worked example is given in the aforementioned CG reduction example/sample code.